# Error: "Operator '==' can't be applied to operators of type 'object' and 'int'

Tags: c#

I have the following block in my code :

```
if (!Userpages.AccessableItems.Where(x => { return x.SelectReturns["Permission_ID"] == 1; }).FirstOrDefault().SelectReturns("AllowDeny"))
{
                Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorized.aspx");              
}
```

where `Userpages` is a variable of customized business object, and `selectReturns` is property of type `Dictionary<string,object>`  but I got an error that

> "Operator '==' can't be applied to operators of type 'object' and 'int'.

I tried to cast '1' as object but it seems also not correct ".
can anyone help me ?!

Comment: Are you missing a cast? probably "(int)" before "x.SelectReturns["Permission_ID"]" ....

Answer (score 7):

Your comparison look like this

```
x.SelectReturns["Permission_ID"] == 1
```

where left side is an object. So cast your `object` into `Int` and then do the comparison.

```
Convert.ToInt32(x.SelectReturns["Permission_ID"])==o
```

Answer (score 0):

If the output of the dictionary-lookup is assured to be of type int, you can do the following:

```
if (!Userpages.AccessableItems
      .Where(x => (int)(x.SelectReturns["Permission_ID"]) == 1)
      .FirstOrDefault().SelectReturns("AllowDeny")
) {
      Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorized.aspx");
}
```

Note: I've also made the linq a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If `x.SelectReturns["Permission_ID"]` returns object of type `System.Int32`, you can cast it:

```
if(!Userpages.AccessableItems.Where(x => (int)x.SelectReturns["Permission_ID"] == 1).FirstOrDefault().SelectReturns("AllowDeny"))
{
    Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorized.aspx");              
}
```

But if it can be another type or any custom type, you can use directly (overloaded) Equals method:

```
if(!Userpages.AccessableItems.Where(x => x.SelectReturns["Permission_ID"].Equals(1)).FirstOrDefault().SelectReturns("AllowDeny"))
{
    Response.Redirect("~/NotAuthorized.aspx");              
}
```